# Reference request: Introductions to current mathematics derived from / related to gauge theories

Tags: reference-request, gauge-theory

I was searching for introductions to current mathematics related to gauge theories.

Can someone suggest some good references?

E.g.

*[Topics in Physical Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848829388) by K. Marathe*

Answer (score 4):

A few suggestions:

- Donaldson and Kronheimer *The geometry of four manifolds*
- Lawson and Michelson *Spin geometry*
- Jost *Geometry and physics*
- GL Naber *Topology, geometry, and gauge fields: Foundations* and *Topology, geometry, and gauge fields: Interactions*
- Lawson *Theory of gauge fields in four dimensions*
- Atiyah *Geometry of Yang-Mills fields*

Comment: Atiyah and Naber are excellent books.